Running pip3 install, and I get a warning on the installation about parsing dependencies
I am running Linux 22.04, with python3, and have installed many modules over the past few months without an issue.
I tried to install a python library for signal and had a similar error, so gave up, and tried slack.
pip3 install slack_sdk
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting slack_sdk
  Downloading slack_sdk-3.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Downloading slack_sdk-3.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (289 kB)
WARNING: Error parsing dependencies of send2trash: Expected matching RIGHT_PARENTHESIS for LEFT_PARENTHESIS, after version specifier
    sys-platform (=="darwin") ; extra == 'objc'
                 ~^
Installing collected packages: slack_sdk
Successfully installed slack_sdk-3.31.0

The command indicates is has been installed, but if I try to run example code, I get a lot of errors:-
./signal.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<programme path>/signal.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slack_sdk import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .web import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/client.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .base_client import BaseClient, SlackResponse
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 11, in <module>
    import uuid
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/uuid.py", line 59, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/platform.py", line 119, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 48, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/<programme path>/signal.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slack_sdk import WebClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient' from partially initialized module 'slack_sdk' (most likely due to a circular import) (/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/__init__.py)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, io
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 48, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/<programme path>/signal.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slack_sdk import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .web import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/client.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .base_client import BaseClient, SlackResponse
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .internal_utils import (
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/internal_utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from asyncio import Future
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import events
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 204, in <module>
    class AbstractEventLoop:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 499, in AbstractEventLoop
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'PIPE' (most likely due to a circular import)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<programme path>/signal.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slack_sdk import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .web import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import WebClient
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/client.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .base_client import BaseClient, SlackResponse
  File "/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 11, in <module>
    import uuid
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/uuid.py", line 59, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/platform.py", line 119, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 48, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/<programme path>/signal.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slack_sdk import WebClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient' from partially initialized module 'slack_sdk' (most likely due to a circular import) (/<directory path>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/__init__.py)



The example code is:-
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import os
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError

client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'])

try:
    response = client.chat_postMessage(channel='#Test', text="Hello world!")
    assert response["message"]["text"] == "Hello world!"
except SlackApiError as e:
    # You will get a SlackApiError if "ok" is False
    assert e.response["ok"] is False
    assert e.response["error"]  # str like 'invalid_auth', 'channel_not_found'
    print(f"Got an error: {e.response['error']}")
    # Also receive a corresponding status_code
    assert isinstance(e.response.status_code, int)
    print(f"Received a response status_code: {e.response.status_code}")


The only item changed from the example from the Pypi website (https://pypi.org/project/slack-sdk/) was the addition of the #! at the start to allow the running of the script without referring to python3 and the change of the #random topic to #test.
I suspect the problem is related to the issue in installing the module using pip3/ pip.
I have tried the same process with a python signal module (pysignald) with the same result.
I have not seen an answer online.
I believe the warning on using pip3 install - if not present - would allow the code to run, but removing the warning is the first step to getting the sample code to work.
I also tried removing the library and reinstalling using pip rather than pip3 without any difference.
My apologies if my question isn't complete, or the answer is intuitive, but I am new to this, and still learning.
Please let me know if there are any questions, and I hope someone might help to solve this.
Many thanks,

Some additional information that might help: what is your version of pip? Have you tried the same thing with a fresh venv and is the error there too? If you're using the same Python env over and over again, sometimes incompatibilities creep up, so generally I have a different venv (or conda env) for each project and based on your question you don't seem to be doing that.

However, the error "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'PIPE'" is absolutely not normal: that smells like a corrupted Python installation, to be honest.

The ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient' from partially initialized module 'slack_sdk' (most likely due to a circular import) seems because you have both slack and slack_sdk installed, see this thread.
